# NodeJs - route parameters crash the file system on a client

Tags: node.js, express

This is my server

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const handlebars = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    extname: 'hbs'
});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

require('./Server/Routes/questionnaire')(app);

app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Public')));

app.listen(8888, function () {
    console.log('Server running on port 8888');
});
```

and I use this route

```
module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/questionnaire', function (req, res) {
        res.render('questionnaire', {
            eventInfo: {
                description: "TEST",
                imgHost: "Resources/img_logo.png"
            }
        });
    });
};
```

the code works fine. When adding a parameter to the route `/questionnaire/:id` no css files or client code is found.

[image: Error]

What am I missing? Using a parameter in my route should have the correct syntax. This error just appears, when using parameters in the routes.

---

**EDIT:**
The whole directory

[image: Directory]

First I use my default HTML **index.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<link href="Style/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Style/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Style/button.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Style/input.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Style/link.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="Client/header.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="header">

</div>

{{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

and I render my `questionnaire.hbs` template

```
<link href="Style/Templates/questionnaire.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="Client/Templates/questionnaire.js"></script>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a `./Public` folder? And if yes is there a `./Public/questionnaire` folder in it?

Comment: Can you please share your html code?

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it helps

Comment: `imgHost: "Resources/img_logo.png"` I think that you need to start your urls with a Slash because if you don't it will use the relative path from your questionnaire folder. So you may need to write you static paths like this: `imgHost: "/Resources/img_logo.png"`

Comment: yes, this worked! I just have to put a `/` to the path

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I have to write `/...`.

When using a parameter, it seems I have to write full paths like

`"/Resources/img_logo.png"`

instead of

`"Resources/img_logo.png"`

Comment: Why did you just delete your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802174/loop-asynchronous-sql-statement-in-nodejs/48802466#48802466 after I wrote a detailed answer and was even working on more options in my answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your app.js

```
//comment this line
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Public')));

//add this middleware
app.use(express.static('./Public'));
app.use('/Style',express.static('./Public/Style'));
app.use('/Client',express.static('./Public/Client'));
```